# Historical S&P500 prices using FinancialData[

Tags: finance

After some poking around, I found how to get the price of the S&P500:

```
FinancialData["^SPX"]` and `FinancialData["^SPX", "Company"]
```

However, I am trying to illustrate the calculation of betas, so I need historical prices, but putting past dates (for example `FinancialData["^SPX", DateObject[DatePlus[Today, -90]]]`) gives `Missing[NotAvailable]`. My workaround has been to use an index fund instead, but I would strongly prefer doing this the right way. Any ideas about how to get historical data for the S&P500 with `FinancialData[ ]`?

By the way I did consult [these answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120208/obtaining-historical-financial-data), but

`WolframAlpha["s&p500 prices from 10/23/2015 to 10/22/2016",{"DateRangeSpecified:Last:FinancialData"}]`

does not produce a `TimeSeries` list. And, yes, I know that if I was connected to Bloomberg, then an interface exists, I am not.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120208/134).

Comment: Oof, that works but doing it in four month intervals is a pain. Thanks, I upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Entity` to feed `FinancialData`:

```
ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData[EntityClass["Financial", "SP500"], {{2016, 1, 1}, Today}]]

DateListPlot[ts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Using `"SP500"` instead of `EntityClass["Financial", "SP500"]` returns the same data.

Comment: The symbol `"^GSPC"` also returns the same data.

Comment: Thanks all. Wrapping in `TimeSeries[ ]` would not produce a list that I could then use to calculate and graph relations with stocks. But it turns out that `FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}]` worked just fine. How could I have found the correct symbol string? I searched for all symbols containing SP with `FinancialData["*SP*", "Lookup"]` but it did not produce SP500.

Comment: @Karsten7. This is my feeble attempt to use the `Entity` framework which is still almost indecipherable to me. :)